# Using jQuery in Apple Instruments, UI Test Automation

Tags: javascript, jquery, soap, instruments

Is there a way to use jquery when scripting in Apples UI Test Automation. When, in Intruments,  I try:

```
#import "jquery-1.4.2.js"
```

I get a warning regarding undefined object window, which is expected since there are no window objects defined, like it would have been in a browser.

But, when I try the same on the Rhino JavaScript engine, using the [EnvJs](http://www.envjs.com/) it works like a charm:

```
$ js
Rhino 1.7 release 2 2010 01 20
js> load('env.rhino.1.2.js')
[  Envjs/1.6 (Rhino; U; Linux amd64 2.6.32-24-generic; en-US; rv:1.7.0.rc2) Resig/20070309 PilotFish/1.2.13  ]
js> load('jquery-1.4.2.js') 
js> jQuery

function (selector, context) {
    return new jQuery.fn.init(selector, context);
}

js>
```

Is there a way to do the same in Apples JavaScript engine in Instruments UI Test Automation?
/Kristian'

PS: What I try to accomplish using jquery, is to make SOAP client requests using the AJAX api in jquery. DS

Comment: But is it possible to send HTTP POST requests using JavaScript in the [Apple] UI Automation?

Comment: I know it has been quite some time, but were  you able to figure out if you can send a POST request from UI Automation?